# Fontawesome 5 SVG with JS: How does svg scale with font-size css property?

Tags: html, css, svg, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

how does FA5 scale **SVG** icons via **font-size** css property? How can I scale this example svg like Fontawesome does? Thank you very much.

```css
svg{
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be scaled via `font-size` like this:

```css
svg {width: 3em; height:3em}

#svg1 {font-size:10px}
#svg2 {font-size:20px}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="49"/></svg>

<svg id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="49"/></svg>
```

Comment: I think you meant  ```heigh: 3em;``` because it won't scale properly when it reaches 3rem width. Could you please edit the answer?

Comment: @J.Doe, yes, that was a typo, sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

With FA5 SVG icons it will append a class to the svg element as default, so you are able to hook into it by using the below

```
<div class="myIcon">
    <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    </svg> 
</div>

.myIcon .svg-inline--fa{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I knew that, look bellow - that's what was I looking for. Thanks anyway.